# Accessing archive of iPhone backups?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, backup, software-update

So I dun goof'd up (tm) while updating a friends iPhone 4 to the latest OS.
I obviously started by creating a back up of the device, but I think I messed up and after the device had factory reset due to the update. I think what happened was after I did the update to the phone I backed it up again because when I went to 'restore' the iphone from a back up (which completed successfully) the iphone was put in its factory state, even asking for a username/password and giving me the whole 'welcome' screen thing.

So either I didn't back up properly the first time or I backed up properly the first time but then I backed up the device again AFTER the update was installed meaning the back up is of a factory reset install of the iPhone.

is this reversible or have I just lost everything (except for photographs which for some reason I was smart enough to back up myself).

I'm mostly trying to get his contacts back at this point...

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky you have more than 1 backup file on your hard disk if you are doing the manual backup. Go to `~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup/` and move the most recent backup (the one that you don't want to restore) temporarily to another location and then try to restore the backup in iTunes again.